# When you press right arrow in terminal during a process "^[[C" shows up. What it means anyway?

Tags: linux, terminal

If you happen to press arrows in Linux terminal while running a mysql query or inside a window where you have a server running a series of characters pop up. The same thing happens if you press the arrows + SHIFT or F2, F3, F4, etc. But if you press other keys they will show up as you would expect.

It is obvious to me that these sequence of characters were created following certain order. So what are they? What do they represent? Who came up with them ? Which computer language do they come from? They look archaic and useless...Should we drop them in the future? Or are they really useful?

4 Arrows

```
^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D
```

SHIFT + Arrows

```
[[1;2A^[[1;2B^[[1;2C^[[1;2D
```

F2-F6

```
^[OQ^[OR^[OS^[[15~^[[17~
```

I searched for an answer to my questions on the web to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that is from a terminal emulator.  The Linux console produces different characters.

In either case, those are generally referred to as *ANSI escape sequences*, which are sent by *special keys* (*function-keys* or *cursor-keys*), usually in the same type of "archaic" form which applications use to control the terminal.

The particular set you have quoted are documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys), and are recognized by terminal applications such as [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html). The corresponding information in ncurses is stored in its terminal database, e.g., [this entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src-entries.html#tic-xterm) (you may have to follow a few links to see all of this).

With that, you may have enough keywords to use with web-searches.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I check the links and realised you are an authentic Olympian God software developer! One of the principal deities of the Software Development pantheon! Thanks again for sharing your knowledge with us!